# Make an executable jar using maven java application in netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am new to Netbeans and Java app development. I just need to know how to create an executable jar using Netbeans. My app contain GUI and taken some dependency library.

The following is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.oli</groupId>
    <artifactId>FFmpegchunker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.oli.ffmpegchunker.MainScreen</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kokorin.jaffree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaffree</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.4</version>
   </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

A jar is created in the target folder but it is not executable.

Comment: Can you try running the jar from command line and see if there are any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to package the dependency inside the executable jar.
It is a 2 step process:
First, copy all required dependencies into a folder:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/libs
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now all the dependencies will be copied in libs folder.

The second step is the creation of an executable and classpath aware jar, with the link to the dependencies copied in the first step:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>
                    com.oli.ffmpegchunker.MainScreen
                </mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The overall pom will look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.oli</groupId>
    <artifactId>FFmpegchunker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/libs
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.oli.ffmpegchunker.MainScreen
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kokorin.jaffree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaffree</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

You can find some simpler approaches for executable jar creation over [here](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) using maven assembly plugin and shade plugin.

Comment: can you post the complite pom.xml based on my pom.xml because am new and little confuser @Faiz

Comment: if i just take jar and make it excutable its not working it can run only from the taget folder why is that?i need to give jar to my client how can i achive this?

Comment: @Samwinishere - use shade plugin as mentioned in the link